# Exim sets sender as <> only for one domain

Tags: exim

Recently I've noticed that mail to one domain does not get delivered, logs stated that their server responded with "no bounces are allowed". However, all rejected messages were normal, not bounces. Then I launched tcpdump to see what's happening, and it showed that for some reason Exim puts no address in sender header, here is the part of packet contents:

> MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=77151

However, in logs Exim shows correct sender for this particular session:

> 2014-03-25 12:17:03 1WSOPQ-0008SD-Ta <= test@***** H=localhost
>   [127.0.0.1] P=smtp S=248 for ***@ukr.net

Also some output from

```
exim -d-all+deliver+dns+expand+lookup+queue_run+resolver+route+transport+verify
```

> 34054 expanding: From ${if
>   def:return_path{$return_path}{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
>   ${if def:sender_address{X-Envelope-From: ${sender_address}
>   }}${if def:received_for{X-Envelope-To: ${received_for}
>
> 34054    result: From MAILER-DAEMON Tue Mar 25 12:36:18 2014 34054
>   X-Envelope-From: test@***
>
> 34069 delivering 1WSOiN-0008rG-De
>
> 34069 reading spool file 1WSOiN-0008rG-De-H
>
> 34069 user=mailnull uid=26 gid=6 sender=test@******

, so sender gets correctly expanded on the way, but on remote subscription it breaks.

That is the only one domain to where Exim sends incorrectly. Neither domain or its IP are  listed in config. I have no idea why did it start doing this.

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed output? It might be you are doing an smtp callout to try to verify the recipient address before actual delivery, or you have some router that changes the sender before smtp delivery..

Comment: @krisku there are no specific routers and I don't use callout. anyways, the problem resolved itself two days later, and never repeated. I can't imagine why and how, and it is not reproducible at the moment so I can't provide any additional output.

Comment: Ok. However the "SIZE=77151" captured from your tcpdump is very far from the size "S=248" in the Exim log, so I think you might have had more than one message going on at a time..

Comment: @krisku yeah, I've added additional information after the creation of this question, so it happened to be from another message to that domain. Sorry for confusing that